# Implementing Fermat Attack using Maple

Tags: encryption, cryptography, maple, prime-factoring

I am trying to implement Fermat Attack in  maple but it is giving me an error stating that     `Error,`(`unexpected`. Super beginner with Maple so if anyone who does have some experience could help, it would be much appreciated.

Also, I am trying to factor an integer that is 125 digits long. Does anyone know any efficient algorithm in Maple or any other program that can handle and factor such a large integers?

```
FermatAtttack:=proc(n::And(posint,odd), maxnumsteps::posint:=10^7,(numsteps::truefalse:=false))
local x, k, r, i, y:
x:=isqrt(n);
if x^2 < n then
  x:= x+1
end if;
k:=2*x+1;
r:=x^2-n;
for i to maxnumsteps while not issqr(r) do
  r:=r+k;
  k:=k+2
end do;
if issqr(r) then
  x:=(k-1)/2;
  y:=isqrt(r)
else
  error "%1 could not facot in %2 iteratioons", n, maxnumsteps
end if;
if not numsteps then
  x-y, x+y
else
  x-y, x+y, i
end if;
end proc:
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Number Field Sieve to factor your 125-digit integer. See [this guide](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/nfs_beginners_guide.html) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a simple syntax error.  Your first line is probably supposed to be

```
FermatAtttack:=proc(n::And(posint,odd), maxnumsteps::posint:=10^7,{numsteps::truefalse:=false})
```

Maple uses the command "ifactor" to factor integers.

Answer (score 0):

In your parameter sequence of the definition of your procedure `FermatAttack`, you have a round-bracketed item within the bracketed parameter declaration, and your error message is due to that.

```
(numsteps::truefalse:=false)
```

Change that to either just,

```
numsteps::truefalse:=false
```

or to,

```
{numsteps::truefalse:=false}
```

according to how you intend on calling it. The second of those is termed a keyword parameter. Here's a short illustration of the difference.

```
FA := proc( ns::truefalse:=false )
    print(ns);
end proc:

FA();
                                 false

FA(true);
                                 true

FB := proc( {ns::truefalse:=false} )
    print(ns);                        
end proc:                           

FB(); # getting the default value
                                 false

FB( ns=false );
                                 false

FB( ns=true );
                                 true

FB( ns ); # a convenience of type truefalse keyword parameters
                                 true
```

If you use the keyword parameter approach then note that the passed argument `true` in the next example doesn't match the keyword (which thus gets its default value).

```
FB( true );
                                 false
```